# How can I fill a feature layer with data from an xlsx\xls spread sheet if the field names are different (mapping)

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, pandas

I'm developing a widget that suppose to take data from a specific spread sheet of an excel file (xlsx or xls) and fill a layer that I created using arcmap pro.. The layer has slightly different field names than the xlsx file mainly because you can't use spaces while naming feature layer fields, so I'm trying to find a way to replace the spaces with underscores and basically to alter the Excel field names.

I have this function that compares between the fields from the excel file and the fields of the layer and then the array that filled with the matching fields between the two passes on to the function that actually adds them. The "insertFields" is the array that contains the matching field names which then I use to fill up the layer but it's not mapping it just checks which fields names are the same and adds the fields that it can add and the rest remain nulls.

What i'm looking for is a tool that can take the Excel field names and make a link between them and the field names of the feature layer.

I want to be able to tell the code that the value of the "Project id" field (in the excel file) suppose to end up in the "Project_id" field (in the layer).

How can I do that?

**the function that does the comparing and appeands the matching fields to the "insertFields" which passes to the next function:**

```
def handleFields(a):
        # Get the input fields
        inputFieldsList = arcpy.ListFields(inputTable)
        for i in inputFieldsList:
            inputFields.append(i.aliasName)

        # Get the output fields
        outputFieldsList = arcpy.ListFields(outputTable)
        for i in outputFieldsList:
            outputFields.append(i.name)

        # Get all the fields from input that exists in output and collect the missing input 
        fields
        for i in inputFields:
            if i in outputFields:
                insertFields.append(i)
            else:
                inputFieldsMissing.append(i)
        # Get all the missing ouput fields
        for i in outputFields:
            if i not in inputFields:
                outputFieldsMissing.append(i)

        del outputFieldsList
```

## Insert Rows from input to output

```
def appendRows(a):
    # Get Integer fields
    integerOutputTableFields = []
    outputTableFields = arcpy.ListFields(outputTable)
    for field in outputTableFields:
        if field.name in insertFields and 'int' in field.type.lower():
            integerOutputTableFields.append(field.name)
    # Read input table
    inputTableCursor = {}
    inputTableToIterate = {}
    inputFieldsToIterate = {}
    isXls = inputTable.split('.')[-1].split('\\')[0] == 'xls'
    isXlsx = inputTable.split('.')[-1].split('\\')[0] == 'xlsx'
    if isXls or isXlsx:
        # arcpy.AddMessage(inputTable.rsplit('\\', 1)[0])
        # arcpy.AddMessage(inputTable.rsplit('\\', 1)[1][:-1])
        # arcpy.AddMessage(insertFieldsForPanda)
        inputTableCursor = pd.read_excel(inputTable.rsplit('\\', 1)[0], sheet_name=inputTable.rsplit('\\', 1)[1][:-1])
        inputTableToIterate = inputTableCursor.index 
        # arcpy.AddMessage('XLS file read using PANDAS')
    else:
        inputTableCursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(inputTable, insertFields)
        inputTableToIterate = inputTableCursor
        # arcpy.AddMessage('TABLE file read using ARCMAP')
    
    outputTableCursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(outputTable, insertFields)
    rowNum = 0
    # Try to add all rows from input table by itrate them and add all fields to new list and try to add the list,
    # if we insert field with type that can not be cast by the system we get error and we set the value to null and put it on the error list.
    # In the case of type int on output table we have problem when we have double on input table becouse it doen't throw error so we need to check it.
    for row in inputTableToIterate:
        rowNum = rowNum + 1
         # skip the first row (the table has 2 header rows)
        if rowNum <= int(rowsToSkip):
            continue
        # Create new list to insert in case i will need to update values to null
        insertRow = []
        fieldIndex = 0
        if isXls or isXlsx:
            inputFieldsToIterate = insertFields
        else:
            inputFieldsToIterate = row
        #for field in row:
        for fieldToInsert in inputFieldsToIterate:
            if isXls or isXlsx:
                field = inputTableCursor[fieldToInsert][row]
            else:
                field = fieldToInsert
            # Check int fields on output table becouse insert allow to insert doubles to int fields by casting them
            # Maybe I can return the code back and do the check after building the row instead of while the row is building.
            try:
                # check if this is int field
                if insertFields[fieldIndex] in integerOutputTableFields:
                    # Check if the value is changed after casting to int, I cast to float first in case the value type is string
                    # If value is not equal I set it to null and put it on the error list.
                    if field != None and float(field) != int(float(field)):
                        raise ValueError('Values are not equal')
##                        field = None
##                        if insertFields[fieldIndex] not in outputFieldsError:
##                            outputFieldsError[insertFields[fieldIndex]] = rowNum
            # In the case that the cast throw exception I catch it and again set value to null and put it on the error list
            # I change the exception catching type to minimize the work for us becose if get to any exception while checking the field it probably have wrong data.
            #except ValueError, ErrorDesc:
            except Exception as ErrorDesc:
                field = None
                if insertFields[fieldIndex] not in outputFieldsError:
                    outputFieldsError[insertFields[fieldIndex]] = rowNum
                    
            insertRow.append(field)
            fieldIndex = fieldIndex + 1
            
        # While the row is not inserted becouse format errors
        # I update the value on the column to null and try again
        # with limit to field count to prevent endless loop
        fieldCount = 0
        rowInserted = False
        while not rowInserted and fieldCount < len(insertFields):
            try:
                fieldCount = fieldCount + 1
                outputTableCursor.insertRow(insertRow)
                rowInserted = True
            except RuntimeError as ErrorDesc:
                try:
                    #arcpy.AddMessage(ErrorDesc)
                    #print re.split(' |\[|\]', str(ErrorDesc))[-2]
                    #arcpy.AddMessage(re.split(' |\[|\]', str(ErrorDesc))[-2])
                    errorField = re.split(' |\[|\]', str(ErrorDesc))[-2]
                    insertRow[insertFields.index(errorField)] = None
                    # If the field doesnt exist yet insert for the report
                    # If we want to report all rows, remove the 'if' and change the value to be list
                    if errorField not in outputFieldsError:
                        outputFieldsError[errorField] = rowNum
                except Exception as ErrorDesc:
                    raise Exception(ErrorDesc)
            except Exception as ErrorDesc:
                arcpy.AddError('Row number ' + str(rowNum) + 'had unknown error, system continue to load good rows, please check:')
                arcpy.AddError(ErrorDesc)
                fieldCount = len(insertFields)
                    
    del inputTableCursor, outputTableCursor, integerOutputTableFields, outputTableFields, inputTableToIterate, inputFieldsToIterate
```

Comment: By “arcmap pro” do you mean ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?

Comment: I mean ArcGIS pro.. why you're asking, I think the layer has little to do with it.. am I wrong?

Comment: If the layer has little to do with it then this may be a pure pandas question that is better researched/asked at [so] either the arcpy references removed.

Comment: don't you think that arcpy.da.SearchCursor() function can receive something like a dictionary to link between the field names?..

Comment: It can take a list of field names as its second parameter or a single field name but not a dictionary. I’m not a potential answerer of your question because I’ve never used pandas in earnest.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python sets to simplify the overlapping or disjoint field names:

```
def handleFields(inputTable,outputTable):
        # Get the input fields
        inputFieldsList = set([f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(inputTable)])

        # Get the output fields
        outputFieldsList = set([f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(outputTable)])

        insertFields = list(inputFieldsList.intersection(outputFieldsList))
        #this will find the fields from inputFieldsList that are not in outputFieldList
        outputFieldsMissing = list(inputFieldsList.difference(outputFieldList))
        #this will find all missing fields
        outputFieldsMissing = list(outputFieldList.difference(inputFieldsList))+ list(inputFieldsList.difference(outputFieldList))

        return outputFieldsMissing, insertFields
```

I don't see in the code you have where you are comparing the pandas column names to the output fields. You could follow a similar approach as you have or use sets. If there is some type of pattern you know will work like replacing spaces with an underscore, you can create a concordance dictionary. You could also add the fields to the outputs. This will be a little trickier but pandas has the property dtypes that will tell you if something is numeric or an object (string).

```
outputTableFields = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(outputTable)]
inputTableCursor = pd.read_excel(inputTable.rsplit('\\', 1)[0], sheet_name=inputTable.rsplit('\\', 1)[1][:-1])
matched = {}
for i,c in enumerate(inputTableCursor.columns):
    if c in outputTableFields:
        matched[c] = c
    elif c.replace(" ","_") in outputTableFields:
        matched[c] = c.replace(" ","_")
    else:
        arcpy.AddField_management(...)
```